# How can I get the currently playing song from the audioscrobbler api?

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, last.fm

I am using the zend framework to get info from the audioscrobbler api. The response format is like this:

```
  <recenttracks user="RJ">
  <track nowplaying="true">
    <artist mbid="2f9ecbed-27be-40e6-abca-6de49d50299e">Aretha Franklin</artist>
    <name>Sisters Are Doing It For Themselves</name>
    <mbid/>
    <album mbid=""/>
    <url>www.last.fm/music/Aretha+Franklin/_/Sisters+Are+Doing+It+For+Themselves</url>
    <date uts="1213031819">9 Jun 2008, 17:16</date>
    <streamable>1</streamable>
  </track>
  ...
</recenttracks>
```

I am accessing elements as such:

```
$track->name
```

How can I get the nowplaying value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Zend Framework API Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Service/Audioscrobbler/Zend_Service_Audioscrobbler.html#artistGetTopTracks) you are getting a SimpleXML object. You can read an attribute of a `SimpleXMLElement` with it's [attributes()](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-element-attributes.php) method:

```
$track->attributes()->nowplaying
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give these a try:

```
$track['nowplaying']
```

or:

```
$track->getAttrib('nowplaying')
```

or:

```
$attributes = $track->attributes();
echo $attributes['nowplaying']
```

I don't see it in the docs anywhere though.

Comment: thx for the tips, i tried those out with no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not really knowing much about this subject (except for the Audioscrobbler protocol), googling for it seems to indicate that `$track->getAttribute("nowplaying")` should do the trick.  HTH.